# Animated GIF and TDrawgrid in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-2007, gif

I am being able to draw the image using something like the code below:

```
ACanvas.Draw(ARect.Left+16, ARect.Top+4, imgGIF.Picture.Graphic )
```

Now the gif for that imgGIF component is being loaded via

```
  GIF := TGifImage.Create;
  GIF.LoadFromFile('path\to\gif\processing.gif');
  GIF.Animate := True;
  imgGIF.Picture.Graphic.Assign(GIF);
```

I am setting

```
GIFImageDefaultAnimate := True;
GIFImageDefaultTransparent := True;
```

The environment is Delphi 2007, using the TGifImage that comes with the Delphi 2007 DVD.
Is this even possible? To display an animated GIF on a TDrawgrid Cell?

I don't think it is since canvas.draw is only drawing the image, not inserting the component into the cell - so as far as I can understand, it is only drawing the firm image on the gif.

Comment: You are right. Of course, you could call `Draw` in a timer, and draw each frame in the animation manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `TGIFImage.Animate` is set to True, calling `Canvas.Draw()` will render the current frame of the animation.  When the `TGIFImage` is placed inside a `TImage`, `TImage` uses the `TGraphic.OnChange` event to automatically redraw the latest frame as the animation is running.  To do the same thing with the `TDrawGrid`, you will have to call `Canvas.Draw()` periodically, such as in a timer whose interval is set to the value of the `TGIFImage.FrameDelay` property.  Otherwise, load the GIF image into a separate `TGIFImage` instance for the `TDrawGrid`'s use so you can utilize the `TGraphic.OnChange` event.